# Ruby: mocking file writes with Flexmock

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mocking

Apologies if this was asked before.

A simple class:

```
class AskSO

  def initialize( filehandle )
    @filehandle   = filehandle
  end

  def library_start
    @filehandle << '<plist version="1.0">'
  end
end
```

A simple unit test using Flex mock

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'flexmock/test_unit'
require 'AskSO'
require 'test/unit'

class AskSOTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    @filehandle = flexmock( "filehandle", "<<" => "" )
  end

  def test_library_start
    @filehandle.should_receive( "<<" ).with( '<plist version="1.0">' ).once
    @AskSOInstance = AskSO.new( @filehandle )
    @AskSOInstance.library_start
  end
end
```

When I run it with `ruby AskSO-test.rb` I get

```
  1) Failure:
test_library_start(AskSOTest)
    [/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/validators.rb:40:in `validate'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/expectation.rb:123:in `flexmock_verify'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/expectation.rb:122:in `each'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/expectation.rb:122:in `flexmock_verify'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/expectation_director.rb:64:in `flexmock_verify'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/expectation_director.rb:63:in `each'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/expectation_director.rb:63:in `flexmock_verify'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/core.rb:76:in `flexmock_verify'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/core.rb:75:in `each'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/core.rb:75:in `flexmock_verify'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/core.rb:191:in `flexmock_wrap'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/core.rb:74:in `flexmock_verify'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/mock_container.rb:40:in `flexmock_verify'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/mock_container.rb:39:in `each'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/mock_container.rb:39:in `flexmock_verify'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/mock_container.rb:32:in `flexmock_teardown'
     /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/flexmock-0.9.0/lib/flexmock/test_unit.rb:26:in `teardown']:
in mock 'filehandle': method '<<("<plist version=\"1.0\">")' called incorrect number of times.
<1> expected but was
<0>.
```

What am I doing wrong? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case someone else stumbles on the same problem - changed the mock definition to

```
def setup
  @filehandle = flexmock( "filehandle" )
end
```

i.e., without the method. For same reason this solves the problem